# Android: Best way to populate ListView from native data source

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, java-native-interface, native

The majority of the app which I'm porting is written in C++. I have the need to display a large amount of rows in a ListView using data retrieved from the native code.

Say for example I have 50,000 rows of data - actually song names. I'm worried about the performance being slow and I'm also worried about using lots of memory unnecessarily.

What is the best way to populate the ListView - should I:

1. Get the JNI code to populate an ArrayList of **all** the items by
   making add() calls invoked from the C++?
2. Some how only populate
   the number of *visible* rows that the ListView actually requests?
3. Something else

It just so happens that the data I am retrieving is also in a SQLite database - not sure if that would help matters or not. Ideally I would like to keep all of the database access within the C++ code but I am open to suggestion before I set out on this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned that the data available in SQLite database, you can access this SQLite database from Android app layer using the SQLite related classes available in Android. It helps you the extra processing of data through JNI layer. Also modification of list items will   be directly done on the SQLite DB rather by passing the data through JNI layer & updating the same in native layer(Here I guess its C++).

Comment: OK, I guess that would probably be the way to go. I would hope in theory that there's less overhead and hopefully there will be a better way than calling add() 50,000 times too. Thanks.